# Merge data from local database to remote database of Mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, realm

I have a remote central database(MongoDb) that must contain all records coming from using a application by many clients!
The application save data in local collection, then should save data in remote database !

we’re good until now… the problem comes when there is no internet, we go in offline mode.

So lets suppose that we have a remote MongoDb Central database and 2 clients : client A and client B => local database A + local database B
(the two databases are independent).
We are offline ! I have created a document doc1 in the Local DB-A and document doc2 in the Local DB-B .

Online mode is active so the db A must push the doc1 in DB central also the db B must push the doc2 in DB central.
I am using MEAN stack application.

1. I have checked ChangeStream, but not sure during network break how it will work..

Anyhelp will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate any of your help or comment on this.

Comment: MongoDB wouldn't fit for purpose. It does not address multi-master writes and offline functionality. Your usecase would require something like couchdb replication https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html or similar.

Comment: I think this can be done with MongoDB Atlas (just from Realm). Please check doc and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the [realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/) and [change-stream](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/), you need to brainstorm do your own logic as per your requirement,

I had the same situation and asked in the MongoDB forum in [this topic](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-sync-local-mongodb-databases-with-atlas-server-databases/111656), but got a suggestion to implement change-stream, I tried but was not worked for me,

After that, I developed my own logic using NodeJS, ExpressJS, and MongoDB driver APIs to sync data from local to live and wise versa,

If I explain to you in simple steps and examples:

- added a timestamp property that is created timestamp for every collection's documents, `_id` objectId will also work

  - ex: `createdAt: ISODate("")`
- created 2 collections for settings in the local server *(one for local to live sync and second for live to local sync)*, that store the db+collection name, timestamp property that is the last sync document's timestamp

  - ex: `dbName.live_to_local_settings` collection

  ```
  {
     "db_collection": "dbName.collectionName",
     "syncProperty": "createdAt",
     "lastSync": ISODate("")
  }, 
  ...
  ```
- created 2 scripts in local server: *(both will execute as provided interval)*

  1. live to local sync:

     - loop `dbName.live_to_local_settings` collection documents and do the below steps for each collection
     - query to live collection *(`live."dbName.collectionName"`)* and check is `createdAt >= settings.lastSync` and sort by `createdAt` in ascending order
     - query to local collection *(`local."dbName.collectionName"`)* and check only above steps found documents by `_id { $in: _ids }`
     - loop the live collections found documents and do the below steps:

       - insert document in the local collection *(`local."dbName.collectionName"`)* if it not exists in local
       - update the document if `_id` exists in local, there are 3 conditions:

         - ignore the update if both dates `local.createdAt == live.createdAt` are equal
         - check if `live.createdAt < local.createdAt` then merges both documents but the primary consideration is the local document because the createdAt is latest, and after merge replace that whole document in both the places local and live collections using replace query
         - check else if `local.createdAt < live.createdAt` then merges both documents but the primary consideration is the live document because the createdAt is latest, and after merge replace that whole document in both the places local and live collections using replace query
       - update `lastSync` date in `dbName.live_to_local_settings` collection, that is document's `createdAt` timestamp
  2. local to live sync:

     - the above steps would be the same but you need to change it query location wise versa

> This looks complex but, works perfectly with less internet connectivity, and resumes when the internet comes back!

Comment: Which software did you use for  tunneling connecting local to live. I checked bitwise SSH and kitty but sometimes they get disconnected and I need to start them manually. Note : I am not using normal MongoDB not the Atlas one.

Comment: I have created own program in NodeJS, ExpressJS, and MongoDB driver APIs.